# How to activate an onmouseover event for whole texts

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for an onmousover code which i cannot find on the internet.

I have created a css box format

```
.box {
float: left;
width: 740px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
```

and the HTML

But i don't know how to activate an onmouseover event so that it will hide all the text and show a new text content when the mouse hovers over it.

Thank you

Comment: Where is this 'new text'? Please show your relevant HTML in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="a">AAA AAA ... </div>
    <div class="b">BBB BBB ... </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 740px;
  height: 300px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color:#C8C8C8;
}
.box:hover{
   background-color:#C8C8FF;
}
.box div.b{
  display:none;
}
.box:hover div.a{
  display: none;
}
.box:hover div.b{
  display: block;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/YJ7an/1/

Hope this helps.

Comment: I RARELY say things like this but i love this website. But i love you more.

Comment: How do i make div class b's background to be another colour? I have tried this:

Comment: .box div.b{
  display:none;
     background-color:#C8C8C8 ; 
}
.box:hover div.a{
  display: none;
     background-color:#C8C8C8 ; 
}
.box:hover div.b{
  display: block;
   background-color:#C8C8C8 ; 
  
} But it dosnt seem to make the whole entire box grey, just the border around the words.

Answer (score 0):

well don't say there is no resource on internet actually there are plenty of website available for onmouseover event. The best way to refer is [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)

And getting to your Question, there several method to trigger onmouseover event and here I have used simple javascript to change the text on triggering onmouseover event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>a
</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function changeMeHere(text)
        {
            var display = document.getElementById('text-to-display');
            display.innerHTML = "";
            display.innerHTML = text;
        }
 </script>
<style>
#box {
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<div id="box" onmouseover="changeMeHere('Yes, this is Onmouseover Text')" >
<div id="text-to-display" >
default text here.
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```